# Route Two Physical Servers Through Same IP

Tags: email, dns, server, webserver

I have been running a simple web server on a Raspberry Pi for about four months now with no issues. Last week I decided I wanted to set up a basic mail server for my small game company. I looked into Dovecot and Postfix but I had major struggles getting them to work on my web server so I gave up on manually configuring them. I did some research and found iRedMail which requires a fresh OS. I set up another Pi and configured ssh proceeding to iRedMail. I got everything set up correctly with mail working over localhost.

My issue now is connecting remotely from my domain name. I guess my question is, can I have two physical servers using the same domain name? Im using GoDaddy as my DNS provider and I have access to A, CNAME, MX, TXT, SRV, and AAAA records. I've been doing a lot of reading and saw I might be able to do this with SRV records?
If not can I migrate my web server from rpi1 over to the rpi2 and run the email server and web server alongside each other?
I'm not to great with web protocols/server stuff but I'm learning.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do they need to have the same name?

Comment: I want to run my web server under example.com and my mail server under mail.example.com. I guess I didn't specify that I want to run the mail server under a sub domain as it was 4 in the morning when I wrote this; I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize. Why do they need to have the same IP address?

Comment: I don't have access to the ISP so I can't request a second public IP...if that's even possible.

Comment: So you have a public ip configured directly on rpi1?

Comment: I'm running the server through my own router in my dorm over the Internet that is provided to me. I have port 80 and 443 open as well as the necessary ports for mysql and other components like ssh and sftp. Rpi1 is using 80 and Rpi2 is using 81 for example.

Comment: I understand that, it is a very common setup. If your rpi1 has a private IP address (from your private subnet), nothing should prevent you from assigning another (different) private IP to rpi2?

Comment: And then, if you (in goddady DNS console) create A records for example.com and mail.example.com, with the same (public) ip address, then all your problems are solved?

Comment: They both have different private ip's, 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1.8 working over local host. I'm just wondering how to remotely access rpi2 through a subdomain of my current domain since you can't set exact port numbers in the godaddy dns panel.

Comment: That depends what precisely you mean by `remotely access`. And seems like you knew how to set it up for rpi1 :). (btw I am pretty sure what you are actually asking, I am just trying to lead you to solution)

Comment: And yes, DNS indeed knows nothing about ports, it will just translate a name to IP address (generally speaking; and forget about SRV records for all practical purposes)

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything working internally then you just need a few more steps to get it working externally.

Presuming you have 1 static IP in your dorm then you need to *forward* ports 25, 465 & 587 to the internal IP of the Pi running the mail server.

With your DNS registrar add an `MX` entry pointing to hostname of your mail server. You will also need to add an `A` record of your mail hostname pointing at your public IP address.

Depending who your ISP is they might not let you run a mail server (Many block the ports to stop unintended abuse/poor admin)if they do you might want to try and get the reverse dns set for your public IP as that will help your sent mail being flagged at an even higher spam level (than it probably will anyway)

You don't need to worry about `SVR` and those 'odd' records - they won't help in your case. The only one that will is a `TXT` record with the `spf` profile.

Comment: All of those ports were open already for the mail server PI. I added an A record for mail and my public IP and did the same for MX with the name of mail that points to mail.domain.com.
When I go to mail.domain.com it lands in /var/www/html on the PI running the web server and not the correct one on the email server. I can see the root directories for my two sites being served.
Could that mean the ISP is blocking those ports?

Comment: can you telnet to you public ip on port 25? you should get the smtp greeting if you can. if not you may be blocked - you need to test that from *another* connection - not the one your trying to setup from.

Comment: That was dumb for me to ask, Im sorry. 25 and 587 are open but 465 is blocked.

Comment: so (maybe) silly question then; did you actually try and email yourself from an external account and see what happens? dont worry about where http requests go - try and sort email first :)